# Как сервер понимает, какие данные отдавать клиенту по протоколу websocket

Tags: сервер, http, websocket, веб-сервер

Как сервер понимает, какой файл исполнять и какие данные отдать браузеру, когда взаимодействие происхдит по протоколу websocket? При работе по протоколу http сервер узнает это из заголовков, есть ли аналог в websocket?

Comment: Никак, вебсокет двусторонний канал связи, клиент и сервер пишут туда и читают оттуда, в соответствии с логикой, которую Вы запрограммируете

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, каждое сообщение от клиента приходит с некоторым набором заголовков и маской и ее надо расшифровывать?

Comment: Заголовки есть только в момент установления соединения, так как websocket продолжатель рода HTTP. Но после того как соединение установлено никаких заголовков более нет, разве что вы сами их сделаете. На установленном соединении обмен происходит произвольными данными в произвольном формате, так как вы это решите. И серверу не надо знать что запускать, потому как вебсокет живет отдельной жизнью - это постоянно запущенный скрипт, который принимает соединения и не завершается никогда

Comment: Есть ли аналог ? ... Смотря для чего. Есть множество разных протоколов для различных применений. Некоторые из них поддерживают браузеры (практически все основанные на http)

Comment: 1. Поднимается соединение. 2. Клиент кидает "эй, сервер, дай мне такие данные" 3. Сервер обрабатывает и кидает в ответ 4. Клиент получает данные. Так как все это асинхронно, и один веб-сокет можно использовать сразу в куче мест, то обычно с ответом сервер присылает информацию для маршрутизации данных (это все должно программировать ВЫ! или использовать либу) - прямо с данными. Например `{"event": "new_post", "data": ...}` Это работает на событиях (событийная модель)

Comment: @Mike, а как же заголовки, которые несут информацию о данных? В RFC написано, что их обязательно указывать. К примеру, фрагментиовано ли сообщение маска и тд, или мы можем просто отправить кусок данных и браузер их примет ?

Comment: @DenverToha А вы решили писать собственную реализацию протокола WebSocket ? Лучше возьмите готовую библиотеку для своего языка, у нее на выходе будут  только данные. И со стороны браузера, в JS WebSocket во всех функциях использует только ваши данные

Comment: @Mike, я реализую академический проект на си, в который требуется включить реализацию WS, если такая библиотека существует для си, и вы мне ее подскажете, я буду очень рад.

Comment: Первый результат гугла https://libwebsockets.org/